# Expert Knowledge Acquisition and Machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, data-augmentation

Having data sets regarding symptoms and diseases such that I use to observe the conditional distributions P(Disease X | Symptom A , Symptom H , Age >20 )   which I use for classification and diagnosis.

Now, a Domain expert comes and says - the data do not reflect reality, Disease X does not come really often with Symptom A.  Or, Combination of Symptom H and A can also lead to Disease Y which never observed in the data.

What is the modern approach to combine the new knowledge that comes from domain experts to "tune" the classifiers / Augment the original data with the expert inputs? Without using just pure rule-base which won't help the model generalizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question is **Bayesian modelling**.

Beta-distributed priors and Dirichlet priors - these are places to start with when you want to combine number statistics with export knowledge of expected distributions. Bayesian modelling is a whole subfield in itself, within statistics.

Comment: Then the expert needs to choose the prior distribution family or the exact mean/variance of the distribution?

Comment: The expert provides the prior parameter values. The Beta-distribution is for variables/outcomes with two possible values, the Dirichlet for more than 2 possible values. The choice of the type of distribution itself is given by your application domain.

Comment: Expert won't give you the parameter values.. only confidence in rules,  that is why i thought about augmentation that will change the distribution some how..

Comment: In the past, I use to work with researchers who elicited such probabilities from physicians through different gaming and estimation techniques. That's where such numbers can be obtained from.

Comment: I know it might be too exhausting but can you elaborate some more? hard to find practical examples and you seem to have valuable knowledge

Comment: Take a look at LC van der Gaag et al (2002), Probabilities for a Probabilistic Network: A Case-study in Oesophageal Carcinoma:
  https://dspace.library.uu.nl/bitstream/handle/1874/2018/2001-01.pdf?sequence=1